# ssh login does't work using key without password

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

It seems that `id_dsa` doesn't exist and it tries `id_ecdsa`, but it's there and I tried to regenerate it several times and still doesn't work. any one has the same issue and solved? or any one know how to deal with it?

```
hadoop@i5:~$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
2f:ea:1d:fa:eb:3b:86:ac:5f:32:0e:10:e1:09:c5:82 hadoop@i5
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ DSA 1024]----+
|ooo              |
|Eo.o             |
| .+              |
|   .             |
|  .     S        |
|   .     .       |
|    ..o.+ .      |
|     ooBoo       |
|    .+*+*+       |
+-----------------+
hadoop@i5:~$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
hadoop@i5:~$ ssh localhost -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA a5:59:74:76:e5:37:42:3a:3b:57:50:be:a6:69:57:63
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /opt/hadoop/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /opt/hadoop/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
hadoop@localhost's password:
```

Comment: it's bad format. this is my first posting and don't know how to format. do I need to write in an editor then posting?

Answer (score 1):

To create a password-less ssh connection, first, you will need to create a key pair (PuTTygen is a good tool for this).

Generate the key. Save both the public and private keys somewhere on your machine. On the server, under your $HOME directory, create a directory called .ssh using `mkdir .ssh` command. Then, create a file named "authorized_keys" via the command `vi .ssh/authorized_keys`. Copy and paste the public key to this file (in vi, `i` goes to insert mode, `ESC` goes back to command mode, and `:wq` writes and quits). Next, adjust your permissions using `chmod 700 .ssh/` and exit out of the server. Finally, on PuTTY, on the left side, click on "connections" to expand the tree. Next, click on SSH, then AUTH. There's a field that says "Private key file for authentication." NAvigate to the directory you saved your private key, and use this file.

The next login should log in without requiring a password.

For windows:
http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-with-putty/

For Linux:
http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

EDIT - Looks like a permissions issue per the comments below.

Comment: I did this with following steps

Comment: 1. ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa

Comment: 2.cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: what's your perms on the .ssh/authorized_keys directory?

Comment: and it used to work and i don't know why when i installed tomcat and mysql and others, it stopped to allow ssh without password. I wanna figure out what wrong with it. thx

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop  599  7月  4 10:41 authorized_keys

Comment: drwx--x--x  2 hadoop hadoop      4096  4/7/2016 10:41 .ssh

Comment: chmod authorized_keys to 700 (or any combination of 7--).

Comment: Happy to help - please mark as answered. Thanks!